# How I can evaluate this:$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\arctan {(\sin(n ! ))}\, $

Tags: trigonometry, power-series

I want to evaluate the following sum

$$
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\arctan {(\sin(n ! ))}\, 
$$
 I can't judge if that sum converge or diverge because $~\lim \sin(n!)~$ dosn't exist, however its seems converge according to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum(+arctan((sin(n!))),+n%3D0+to+infty) from it's partial sum.

Now I have started my idea by : we have $$\arctan x= x\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1+t^2x^2} dt~.$$ In other side we have $$ \sin(x!)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n} x!^{1+2n}}{(2n+1)!}~.$$ Now we have from both definition of $\sin $ and $\arctan $ using series and integral representation we replace each thing in the titled sum , we w'd get :$$\sum\arctan \sin (x!)= x\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1+t^2x^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n} x!^{1+2n}}{(2n+1)!} dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n} xx!^{1+2n}}{(2n+1)!} \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1+t^2x^2}dt~,$$ Then I can't get the next step its complicated, may am not familiar with integral interchange  ?

Comment: If $\lim \sin(n!)$ doesn't exist, how can the $n$th term of the series go to $0$?

Comment: dosn't exist have two meaning may it has 2 differents limit which is not possible here or may dosn't exist yet as our case , In my guess we can't only pass a test of convergence however it can be

Comment: The series can't converge unless the $n$th term goes to $0$, right?  Convergence tests are pointless.

Comment: The sum doesn't seem to converge, according to Wolfy.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik $\arctan(x)\to 0$ if and only if $x\to 0$

Comment: Step 1: find a formula for $\arctan\sin x$.

Comment: How is the work on a formula for $\arctan(\sin x)$ coming along, zeraoulia?

Comment: Why do you have any reason to expect that a closed form exists? The composition of the $\arctan$, $\sin$, and $n!$ seems rather arbitrary. Perhaps you should try to evaluate something a little more simple first.